# Name of this Forked Fin Fish with Teeth Caught in Miami River, Florida, USA

Tags: fishing, rivers, fish-identification

What type of fish is this?

I caught this fish in the Miami River in Southern Florida, USA. This river is brackish I believe, so I am not sure whether it is saltwater or freshwater. It is brown, green, and white. The head is wider than the rest of the tube shaped body and is full of teeth. There is a fin on the top that is just down when I took some of the pictures. It was no more than 10 inches long and probably not much wider than an inch in diameter.

It looks sort of similar to a snake-head fish, but this fish has a forked caudal fin.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [Inshore Lizardfish](https://www.filmingflorida.com/daily-species/inshore-lizardfish/). The coloring and [range](https://www.fishbase.se/summary/2719) are right and so is the description of the head and the teeth.

It looks like they are edible but not deliberately caught by most people.